# How to customize job description in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

When reading or writing RDDs or Datasets/DataFrames, I usually use the function `SparkContext.setJobDescription` to customize the display on the Spark UI and make it more readable.

However, it looks like this function does not work when streaming (Structured Streaming with readStream/writeStream). How to programmatically customize the Job Description (or similarly the Job Group) on the Spark UI when Structure Streaming? Is there something equivalent to `SparkContext.setJobDescription`?